# Attempt to assign property "status" on null in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I got this error after i click the approve button
can someone help me fix this error, I'm beginner in laravel

[image]

controller

```
    public function approved(Request $request)
{   
    try{
        $leaves = LeaveAdmin::find($request->id);
        $leaves->status =  'Approved';
        $leaves->save();

        DB::commit();
        Toastr::success('Leave Request Approve Successfully','Success');
        return redirect()->back();
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        
        DB::rollback();
        Toastr::error('Failed to Approve Request','Error');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

blade view

```
<div class="modal custom-modal fade" id="approve_leave" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-header">
                        <h3>Leave Status</h3>
                        <p>What do you want to do with this request?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-btn delete-action">                            
                        <div class="row">
                            @csrf
                            <input type="text" name="id" class="e_id" value="{{ $leaves->id}}">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <a href="{{ route('Approved') }}" class="btn btn-primary continue-btn">Approve</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary cancel-btn">Reject</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my approve modal and it has error when i click the approve on this modal

Comment: `$leaves = LeaveAdmin::find($request->id);` returns null, so probably the leave doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Check if  $leaves exist

```
$leaves = LeaveAdmin::find($request->id);

if( isset($leaves) && !is_null($leaves)) {
    $leaves->status =  'Approved';
    $leaves->save();
    DB::commit();
    Toastr::success('Leave Request Approve Successfully','Success');
    return redirect()->back();

} else {
    // do the rest part...
}
```

Comment: the error was gone but it won't save.

Comment: @Jay-arCristobal are you trying to insert a new record or update an existing record?

Comment: i was trying to update the record by approving the leave request

Comment: LeaveAdmin::find($request->id) returns null which means there's no record which id is equal to $request->id . Can you verify that $request->id  record  really exists in the database ? Also please verify that you're passing the right id from frontend.

Comment: i put input type="text" with value="{{ $leaves->id}} to see the id number, and i see an id and it is the right id that i also see in table database

Comment: @Jay-arCristobal please share the blade code where you're putting the value value="{{ $leaves->id}}

Comment: i edit the question, and put the blade code for {{$leaves->id}}

Answer (score 0):

These is happened because `$leaves` return `null`.

Therefore use the `findOrFail` method. and also shorten the code.

```
        $leaves = LeaveAdmin::findOrFail($request->id);
        $leaves->status =  'Approved';

        if ($leaves->save()) {
            DB::commit();
            Toastr::success('Leave Request Approve Successfully','Success');
            return redirect()->back();
        }else{
            DB::rollback();
            Toastr::error('Failed to Approve Request','Error');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
```

Comment: the error was gone but the page display 404 | Not found